# Mouse Is Very Laggy On Windows Server 2016 Very Slow on Virtualbox 6.0.8

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2016

I recently built a computer in order to run multiple VM'S at the same time.

My computer specs:

- Ryzen 7 2700X
- 16GB DDR4 (3000 MHz)
- AORUS GAMING 5 WI-FI
- 500GB WD M.2 SSD
- 4TB WD HDD

An issue I'm having is that when I'm using the mouse inside my Windows Server 2016 VM, it is extremely laggy, and I can't figure out why. 
Edit: I'm only running one VM at a time, and both Virtualbox and the actual VM are on the SSD.

How can I fix it?

Comment: That's not a computer you would want to use multiple VM's at the same time in it. Although it might be powerful for personal use, it's not for virtualization. Are you using the WServer 2016 VM along with others VM's at the same time?

Comment: There's no problem using a Ryzen for virtualization.  OP: Please edit and add: How many VMs are you running? Where are the VMs located, SSD or HDD? VirtualBox Additions installed in VMs?